# How to Set Values To Excel Sheet Cells

Tags: c#

I am trying to set an Excel sheet specific cells starting at column A and second Excel sheet row. I wrote the following code:

```
if (!File.Exists(AppConfiguration.FilePath))
{
    throw new FileNotFoundException("File Not Found. The requested template.xlsx was not found on the server");
}

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlsx = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Workbook workbook = null;

try
{
    workbook = xlsx.Workbooks.Open(AppConfiguration.FilePath, ReadOnly: false, Editable: true);
    Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[1];
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range cells = worksheet.Cells["$A"];
    List<Analytics> list = (List<Analytics>)data;

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)cells[i + 1, 0]).Value = list[i].ProductShare;
        ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)cells[i + 1, 1]).Value = list[i].MarketPotential;
    }

    workbook.Save();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    throw new Exception("Error while processing file");
}
finally
{
    workbook.Close(SaveChanges: true);
    xlsx.Quit();
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
}
```

However, I always get an Exception at

```
(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)cells[i + 1, 0]).Value = list[i].ProductShar
```

Comment: What does the exception message say? Is it maybe `IndexOutOfRangeException`?

Comment: I would suggest you use an existing plugin, like `EPPLUS` there is tons of examples online, it is simple to use and no headache when deploying to a 3rd party server like godaddy for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i< list.Count; i++)
{
   worksheet.Range[string.Format("A{0}", i + 2].Value = list[i].val;
}
```

Starting at A2 I begin to write the values within my list which is what I was seeking for! Thanks for all of you for your times and considerations!

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, indexes begin with 1, therefore `cells[i + 1, 0]`is invalid, use `cells[i + 2, 1]` instead.

Comment: @Amr.Mohammad87: What do you mean with "did not work for me"?

Comment: I tried to use cell indices like cell[rowindex, columnindex] = val but I was getting an Exception when hitting that statement. I do not remember the Exception but I can redo the statement and giving you the Exception detail I was having!